# How to inclide tspecials(<," etc.) in URL for HttpServer?

Tags: java, http

I have implemented simple com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer application using one of examples in the internet.
Server get request as expected except for one exception: 
if url contains tspecials: " or '<' "/" request doesn't reach the server at all.
Using simple java.net.ServerSocket all works great and request received where all tspesials are encoded, which is great for me, but i prefer use HttpServer.

for example request: http://127.0.0.1/MyApp/Test?var=<xml id=“1“>value</xml>
works for ServerSocket and not working for HttpServer.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i can't modify client request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode your urls on the client side, using the % notation:

http://127.0.0.1/MyApp/Test?var=%3Cxml+id%3D%271%27%3Evalue%3C%2Fxml%3E

On the server side, you should use URI.getRawQuery() in case the query contains & characters, and décode parameter values with URLDecoder.decode.

Comment: Thank you,why when i use ServerSocket i don't need to do that and request achieve server already encoded exactly as in your example, i think that the problem is in HttpServer

Comment: With a ServerSocket you must implement the http protocol your self. If your implementation doesn't require url encoding, then it is not compliant with the standard. So if you want to implement http, HttpServer is fine; if you want to implement a custom protocol, you will need to provide the implementation for it.

Comment: does IE encode url and my Server should get Url already encoded

Comment: Maurice, i am sorry for not understanding.
If IE encode uri into valid string so why HttpServer reject it?

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: Well, it you type the address as-is in IE's address bar, it will refuse it because it is an incorrect address (firework on the other hand will encode it). This is an IE issue, it is not related to what you have on the server side. But if the request is produced by a form, it will be correctly encoded.

Comment: I found that IE8 doesn't encode some tspecials like '>' and '<' but do encode some others, after trying uri from FF all works great.
thanks a lot for the answer!!!!